# Go Lint Installation

Tags: go

I'm new into go and im trying to implement [golint](https://github.com/golang/lint) for code static analysis code.  Followed the instructions on the installation and when I try to run through the console `golint ./...` it says `zsh: command not found: golint`. Could anyone point me out what i'm doing wrong.